# Convert Array to Json in Mongodb Aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, parquet, amazon-athena, presto

I have a Mongo Document in below format:

```
{
    "id":"eafa3720-28e2-11ed-bf07"
    "type":"test"
    "serviceType_details": [
        {
            "is_custom_service_type": false,
            "bill_amount": 100
        }
    ]
}
```

"serviceType_details" Key doesn't have any definite schema.

Now I want to export it using MongoDB aggregate to Parquet so that I could use Presto to query it.

My Pipeline Code:

```
db.test_collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "id": "something"
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            ...
        },
    }
    {
        "$out" : {
            "format" : {
                "name" : "parquet",
                "maxFileSize" : "10GB",
                "maxRowGroupSize" : "100MB"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Now I want to export the value of "serviceType_details" in json string not as array ( when using current code parquet recognises it as an array)

I have tried $convert,$project and it's not working.

Currently the generated Parquet schema looks something like this:

[image]

I want the generated Parquet schema for "serviceType_details" to have as string and value should be stringify version of array which is present in mongo document.

Reason for me to have need it as string is because in each document "serviceType_details" details have completely different schema, its very difficult to maintain Athena table on top of it.

Comment: What do you mean "in json string not as array"? Can you give an example of what the output field for the document should look like?

Comment: I want the generated Parquet schema for "serviceType_details" to have as string and value should be stringify version of array which is present in mongo document. @user20042973 I have also updated my question.

Comment: You can have `array(json)` (`array<json>`) as column type in presto

Comment: @GuruStron in DDL or select query? if DDL can you give me an small example?

Comment: @GauravSrivastava it depends on how you setup your table in Athena. Currently I don't have access to it, so will not be able to help you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [$function](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/) operator to define custom functions to implement behaviour not supported by the MongoDB Query Language

It could be done using "[$function](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/)" like this:

```
    db.test_collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "id": "something"
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            newFieldName: {
                $function: {
                    body: function(field) {
                        return (field != undefined && field != null) ? JSON.stringify(field) : "[]"
                    },
                    args: ["$field"],
                        lang: "js"
                }
            },
        },
    }
    {
        "$out" : {
            "format" : {
                "name" : "parquet",
                "maxFileSize" : "10GB",
                "maxRowGroupSize" : "100MB"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

> **Executing JavaScript inside an aggregation expression may decrease performance. Only use the $function operator if the provided pipeline operators cannot fulfill your application's needs.**